# Google Security Command Center - how to export findings in JSON format

Tags: json, security, command, center

Using this example:

```
from google.cloud import securitycenter

# Create a client.
client = securitycenter.SecurityCenterClient()

# organization_id is the numeric ID of the organization. e.g.:
# organization_id = "111122222444"
org_name = "organizations/{org_id}".format(org_id=organization_id)
# The "sources/-" suffix lists findings across all sources.  You
# also use a specific source_name instead.
all_sources = "{org_name}/sources/-".format(org_name=org_name)
finding_result_iterator = client.list_findings(all_sources)
for i, finding_result in enumerate(finding_result_iterator):
    print(
        "{}: name: {} resource: {}".format(
            i, finding_result.finding.name, finding_result.finding.resource_name
        )
    )
```

I would like to export all the finding as a JSON array, however type(finding_result.finding) returns:
class 'google.cloud.securitycenter_v1.types.Finding'

using json.dumps(finding_result.finding) results in an error that it is not JSON serializable.

Using the gcloud SDK this is achievable by specifying "--format json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

You have to add the following import `from google.cloud.securitycenter import ListFindingsResponse`

And then inside the loop you should add the following line

`ListFindingsResponse.ListFindingsResult.to_json(finding_result)`

So the solution should be as the following

```
from google.cloud import securitycenter
from google.cloud.securitycenter import ListFindingsResponse

# Create a client.
client = securitycenter.SecurityCenterClient()

# organization_id is the numeric ID of the organization. e.g.:
# organization_id = "111122222444"
org_name = "organizations/{org_id}".format(org_id=organization_id)
# The "sources/-" suffix lists findings across all sources.  You
# also use a specific source_name instead.
all_sources = "{org_name}/sources/-".format(org_name=org_name)
finding_result_iterator = client.list_findings(all_sources)
for i, finding_result in enumerate(finding_result_iterator):
    print(
        ListFindingsResponse.ListFindingsResult.to_json(finding_result)
    )
    print(
        "{}: name: {} resource: {}".format(
            i, finding_result.finding.name, finding_result.finding.resource_name
        )
    )
```

Comment: Nice! That's for that.